# Postgres: dynamic offset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with news. Let's call this table `news`. Bunch of users are continuously inserting new rows into `news`. A user currently browsing news feed (data from `news` table). How can i make pagination consistent, keeping in mind the fact, that while a user browsing, say, first page, other users are inserting more data in it. So, if the first page had, say 18 news, then i need to use `OFFSET 18`, but in this case i will retrieve wrong data, because new news already have been inserted.

How do i implement pagination properly?

Comment: Is the pagination ordered by news insertion timestamp? Has the row an unique id?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, rows have both uid and insertion timestamp. Should i make pagination be based on insertion timestamp instead of offset? I'm not sure, is it possible to have more than one row with unique timestamp? I mean, if it's within a single table, can pg insert faster than one row per ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the newest and oldest row timestamp of the page in the application client. If it is a web app then the `next` and `previous` links would be something like:

```
<a href="/news?newest=2016-08-06+20%3A17%3A05.882252%2B00">Previous</a>
<a href="/news?oldest=2016-08-05+20%3A17%3A05.882252%2B00">Next</a>
```

Then pass the value of the one you receive from the client to the query and the other as `null`:

```
(
    select *
    from (
        select *
        from news
        where ts > :newest
        order by ts
        limit 20
    ) s
    order by ts desc
)
union all
(
    select *
    from news
    where ts < :oldest
    order by ts desc
    limit 20
)
```

It is very unlikely that two insertions would happen at the same millisecond.

Comment: i use GUID v4, so the `>` operator is not applicable.